# How to add new cities in nlp-compromise?

Tags: nlp, nlp-compromise

I am using compromise module to extract places from a paragraph, but how can I add new cities to this module?

`var r = nlp("I live in San Francisco").places().out("text")` => gives "San Francisco"

But, `var r = nlp("I live in Dallas").places().out("text")` => gives blank response.

So, I want to add new cities to compromise module, could you please guide me where and how can I do that.

Comment: Guys, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lexicon={
    "Dallas": "Place"
}

var r = nlp("I live in Dallas", lexicon).places().out("text")
```